# PyQt/TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, QString found`

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, pyqt

I have the following code. I had made a GUI interface and i wan't to
store the images in a folder that the program will be created.

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

I also tried to make String from Qstring,but didn't worked..or maybe,i
don't know how to save the images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If `face_img` is a list you will have to convert all elements separately:

```
face_img = [unicode(elem, encoding="UTF-8") for elem in face_img]
```

Or, convert only the first element when you use it:

```
cv2.imwrite(folder + '/' + str(counter) + '.jpg', unicode(face_img[0], encoding="UTF-8"))
```

However, typically you don't need to convert from `QString` to `str` yourself. Usually `PyQt` does the conversion automatically. The fact that you encounter a `QString` is strange. This is the underlying issue that needs to be investigated IHMO, the fixes above are just hacks around the actual problem.

I suspect that somewhere in the `operatii` module a `QString` is created explicitly. However, I cannot check this because I don't have the `operatii` module. You code example is not **complete**. Please read this post on [how to make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By posting an MCVE you will get you a lot more help in the future.

Comment: i have post operatii module.

Comment: I can't see it in the operatii module either. You need to debug this by adding print statements where you print the type (and value) of the `face_img` variable. Work your way back until you reach code that is not from you. Then you know the root cause of the issue (ie.e. which statement causes it to be a `QString`) and can think of a solution or work-around.